# Bug in sklearn CountVectorizer with preprocessor and lowercase?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I do not know if I have encountered a possible bug in the sklearn `CountVectorizer` or if I am simply misunderstanding something.

I am working with a small corpus of texts which contain a variety of parenthetical strings, only some of which need to be removed. After some experimentation, I decided simply to go with a list of those parentheticals, a subset I am including below:

```py
parentheticals = [ "\(laughter\)", "\(applause\)", "\(music\)", "\(video\)" ]
```

Because I have found no way to workaround `CountVectorizer`'s requirement that it receive a string, or list of strings, I went with this small regex function:

```py
def clean_parens(text):
    new_text = text
    for rgx_match in parentheticals:
        new_text = re.sub(rgx_match, ' ', new_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return new_text
```

I then passed this to `CountVectorizer` as a `preprocessor` argument:

```py
vec2 = CountVectorizer(preprocessor = clean_parens )
X2 = vec2.fit_transform(texts)
```

On the first run, I noticed my feature set had grown from 53k to 58k for ~1700 texts. When I inspected the feature names, I saw that I had both uppercase and lower case terms:

```py
print(vec2.get_feature_names())
---
... 'Waves' ... 'waves'
```

When I included `lowercase=True` in the `CountVectorizer`, I got no change in my results. Is this because the `preprocessor` takes precedence? (This is not how I understood the documentation.)

A simple change to the little regex function above sets everything right:

```py
def clean_parens(text):
    new_text = text
    for rgx_match in parentheticals:
        new_text = re.sub(rgx_match, ' ', new_text.lower(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return new_text
```

I'm happy with this, but if someone could explain what I misunderstood about the `CountVectorizer`, that would be great. I feel like it's a cabinet saw, and I'm used to using a handheld circular saw: it's power is somewhere between might and magic in the hands of someone like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great catch!

I wouldn't look at this as actual bug, but it is a lack of documentation. Possibly there has to be an error/warning message raised when `preprocessor` is `callable` and `lowercase=True`.

FYI, lower casing happens in the default preprocessor function [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L49). Hence, when you override the preprocessor with a callable, the lower casing would not happen.

I have raised this issue [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17348).

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and for the pointer to the issue). I now feel less crazy and even less like a noob.